# Visual studio online. Migrate a project from one account to another

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I do have two visual studio online accounts:

- mypersonalaccount.visualstudio.com (free basic) and
- mycompanyaccount.visualstudio.com  (paid)

I started a small project into my personal one a few years ago. Now this project grows up and we create a little company.

I would like to change this project from my personal account to the my company account. in order to take advantage of the paid features.

How can I migrate a project from one account to another?

I would like to change the ownership for all data, no just the code repository but all tasks and sprints data too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such tool provided by Microsoft. Microsoft supports the [migration from Team Foundation Server on premise to Visual Studio Team Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/11/16/import-your-tfs-database-into-visual-studio-team-services/).

What I would suggest is to either use alternative tools like the [vsts-sync-migration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration), or write your own PowerShell scripts leveraging the [VSTS REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) to move the data you need.